# 3rd party hosted solution for project management & source control?

Tags: project-management, teamwork, time-management

I am looking for a SAAS solution that offers project management, time tracking, invoicing and file sharing (to share with clients) as well as source control, work item management and team management for a programming team. In other words, a complete solution for a consulting programmer/programming team. 
I am looking at aceproject.com, zoho, basecamp, etc, but they all miss one of more of these features.

Do you know any solution to recommend?

Answer (score 2):

I use [assembla](http://assembla.com). It has everything you ask for except invoicing. I use [freshbooks](http://freshbooks.com) for that. I haven't found a single product that offers absolutely everything. If you can use multiple services, then [Rally](http://rallydev.com) was awesome for project management.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for a lot! The standard answer, on this site, is [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/).

> FogBugz is the world's easiest bug
>   tracking system, built for teams who
>   are serious about shipping great
>   software.
>
> cooperate with teammates meet
>   deadlines maintain control of your
>   projects

Another popular option is [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).

> Redmine is a flexible project
>   management web application. Written
>   using Ruby on Rails framework, it is
>   cross-platform and cross-database.

Redmine can be easily integrated with your favourite version control system (e.g. Git, Mercurial, SVN, CVS, etc.) and look at [Hosted Redmine](https://www.hostedredmine.com/) for a potential web host.